# I want to know what value is fetched by the variable in knockout js

Tags: knockoutjs

Is their anyway to debug the knockout js code by putting alert to popup the

message or as console log s anyway can  know Please

Comment: need more? like which file and which function? explain more

Answer (score 1):

To debug data in knockout js you can use bellow code:

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></div>
```

**OR**

```
<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sheshgiri's answer may help, if not there is a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en) that is designed for debugging KO.